# Using Guzzle Instead Of cURL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I was using Virtual Pos on my own classes. But i want to decide to convert my project to laravel project.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vPOSData);

$ch = curl_exec($ch);
@curl_close ($ch);
echo $ch;
```

When I'm using this code directly in Laravel it is not working. When I check internet, Guzzle is best choice for handling this process.

How can I do it exactly in Guzzle ?

UPDATE:

Here is my data

```
array:20 [
"clientid" => "*********"
"amount" => "27.87"
"oid" => 14532858
"okUrl" => "http://laravel/tr/order/**1/success"
"failUrl" => "http://laravel/tr/order/**1/fail"
"islemtipi" => "Auth"
"taksit" => ""
"commission" => null
"storetype" => "3d_pay"
"cardHolder" => "cihan küsmez"
"pan" => "4531****31442283"
"Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Month" => "12"
"Ecom_Payment_Card_ExpDate_Year" => "18"
"cv2" => "001"
"rnd" => "0.88093200 1447345882"
"hash" => "1phjMQWYUkmJRXj283lonh7GAZE="
"lang" => "tr"
"currency" => 949
"customerIP" => "127.0.0.1"
"vpos_name" => "****** vPOS"
```

]

when i post with guzzle like the code below i'm getting a blank page.

```
    $client = new Client();
    return $client->post($this->_server, $vPOSData);
```

Comment: Have you tried something, or you're just here with the "gimme hte codez!!" mentality?

Comment: First of all you need to specify why it's not working. Because if you plan to use Guzzle with cURL, it will most likely do the same things behind the scenes, that you're attempting now and it probably still won't work.

Comment: @JosephSilber you can check my profile. I'm not begging for code. :)  I think i couldn't tell what i am imagining.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest of use cases, Guzzle can be used as follows:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post($uri, [
    'form_params' = > $array_of_parameters,
]);
```

`$response` is an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`, an implementation of `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`.

More information is available from the [documentation](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Answer (score -1):

### If you still want to request with cURL

> First make sure you have enabled cURL extension

### cURL Request Function

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
  $postData = '';
   //create name value pairs seperated by &
   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

### How to use the function

```
$params = array(
   "name" => "Ravishanker Kusuma",
   "age" => "32",
   "location" => "India"
);

echo httpPost("http://hayageek.com/examples/php/curl-examples/post.php",$params);
```

reference : http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/

Comment: Dear Rameez, i've already using cURL in my project. I converted to Laravel that's why there exists a problem with my previous code.  May be CSRF protection caused the problem ?

Comment: @CihanKüsmez Post the error you're getting, we can't image what's not working if you give no information about the problem.

Comment: Laravel is php, you don't need to change your curl function when converted to laravel and  how come csrf causing problem since curl is an external request?